# Recursive linear search - branch style and layout

Tags: javascript, recursion

Is my layout of the `if/else` statement reasonable?

It feels clumsy to me to spread the termination condition over the first three lines of the function. Can I squeeze it into one or two lines? Would it help if I used the ternary operator? How can I make the JavaScript more idiomatic (while still using recursion)?  Any other improvements?

```js
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  if (sentence.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1));
  };
};
```

```js
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  if (sentence.length == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1));
  };
};

// Unit tests
var assert = function(code) {
  if (eval(code)) {
    document.write(code + " test passed.<br>");
  }
  else {
    document.write(code + " test FAILED.<br>");
  };
};

assert("!containsA('')");
assert("containsA('A')");
assert("!containsA('a')");
assert("containsA('HAH!')");
assert("!containsA('carrots')");
```

I have simplified details that are not relevant to my question. This simpler version attempts to reimplement `String.prototype.contains()`. If I convert my string to an array I could use `Array.prototype.find()` but my hunch is that would be less readable.

Comment: Combining everything into one ternary seems even clumsier looking to me. I'd stick with mjolka's answer.
return sentence.length == 0 ? false : (sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1));

Comment: In Ruby, I can write `return false if sentence.length == 0` as a tidy way to put the termination condition in one line. Does Javascript offer a one-line equivalent to block-structured if?

Comment: A non-block structured if :')
`if(sentence.length == 0) return false;`
That's pretty much the only thing I can think of. (Right now, at least)

Comment: I wish I could accept all the answers. I learned a lot from all of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I make the JavaScript more idiomatic?

By using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  return sentence.indexOf('A') != -1;
};
```

---

As your update specified that you want to use recursion, let's see what we can do.

Cleaning up, we can remove the `else` (and the extraneous semi-colon).

```
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  if (sentence.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1));
};
```

Or you can write it more succinctly, but I would say at the cost of readability

```
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  return sentence.length > 0 &&
    (sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1)));
};
```

Now we could end up creating a lot of substrings. To avoid this, we can pass an index into the string

```
var containsA = function(sentence, i) {
  i = i || 0;
  if (i >= sentence.length) {
    return false;
  }
  return sentence[i] === 'A' || containsA(sentence, i + 1);
};
```

Or

```
var containsA = function(sentence, i) {
  i = i || 0;
  return i < sentence.length &&
    (sentence[i] === 'A' || containsA(sentence, i + 1));
}
```

---

*In case this is not homework or a thought exercise...*

Don't do this. By using recursion (and `substr`) to solve this, you're simultaneously making your code less efficient, in terms of both time *and* memory, and less readable. As @Guffa pointed out, it may even blow the stack.

The function `containsA` has no reason to exist. Just use `indexOf` where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process the string that way, you shouldn't use recursion at all. What you are doing is simply a loop disguised as recursion:

```
function containsA(sentence) {
  while (sentence.length > 0) {
    if (sentence[0] == 'A') return true;
    sentence = sentence.substr(1);
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you want to do recursion you should split the work into equal smaller parts instead of shaving off a single character at a time, so that you won't be doing recursion as deep as there are characters in the string:

```
function containsA(sentence) {
  if (sentence.length <= 1) {
    return sentence == 'A';
  } else {
    var middle = sentence.length / 2;
    return containsA(sentence.substr(0, middle)) || containsA(sentence.substr(middle));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your second way, while using less stack space, makes \$2n - 1\$ calls to `containsA` in the worst case, compared to \$n + 1\$ calls in the original.

Comment: @mjolka: Yes, if you implement recursion correctly for these kind of theoretical implementations, you get that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question in the comments you could do the following:

```
var containsA = function(sentence) {
  if (sentence.length == 0) return false;
  return sentence[0] === 'A' || containsA(sentence.substr(1));
};
```

Of course people will always have different opinions, but here's a few other statements supporting the use (or non-use) of braces.

Note that these are not Java/JavaScript specific. (But since the syntax of the actual subject is similar, I feel they still apply)

#### Other stackexchange questions regarding if-else coding style:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no

Accepted Answer:

> ....Therefore, I prefer to just put everything on one line if it's sufficiently short and simple:
>
> `if(condition) statement;`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434760/one-line-if-statements

Highest rated answer:

> if you should really use one line if
>
> `if(condition) statement=new assignment;`
>   will be better since its one line, it should contain one operation.

#### Other sources:

http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html

One of various samples (note the lack of braces for the single-statement conditional):

> For the body of the function, our recommended style looks like this:
>
> ```
> if (x < foo (y, z))
>   haha = bar[4] + 5;
> else
>   {
>     while (z)
>       {
>         haha += foo (z, z);
>         z--;
>       }
>     return ++x + bar ();
>   }
> ```

http://www.mono-project.com/community/contributing/coding-guidelines/

> Avoid using unnecessary open/close braces, vertical space is usually limited:
>
> good:
>
> ```
> if (a)
>     code ();
> ```
>
> bad:
>
> ```
> if (a) {
>     code ();
> }
> ```
>
> Unless there are either multiple hierarchical conditions being used or that the condition cannot fit into a single line.

Comment: I didn't realize I could replace a code block with a single statement, so thank you. Is a single-line `if` idiomatic?

Comment: I wouldn't do that. It tends to make your code error prone.

Comment: Sentiment on several questions asked on stackexchange sites is that curly braces have the biggest preference, but *short* functions / 1 line conditionals can be used in cases like yours. And they MUST be placed behind the if clause to maximize readability if you insist on using this style.

Comment: I like the answer's quotes from style guides, even if from C# and C. Relevant SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860654/javascript-single-line-if-statement-best-syntax-this-alternative